# Yarn install command dont run correctly

Tags: yarnpkg

My env

```
Yarn version: 3.1.1
Node version: v16.12.0
Ubuntu: 20.04
```

I created a new project at `~/projects/test-yarn` then run command in test-yarn folder and got error

```
yarn init

yarn add vue

Usage Error: The project in /home/MY_NAME/package.json doesn't seem to have been installed - running an install there might help

$ yarn add [--json] [-E,--exact] [-T,--tilde] [-C,--caret] [-D,--dev] [-P,--peer] [-O,--optional] [--prefer-dev] [-i,--interactive] [--cached] [--mode #0] ...
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-yarn",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1"
}
```

It looks like yarn always run at /home/MY_NAME/ folder.

Pleas help to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

I found the root cause:

At `/home/MY_NAME/` has a `yarn.lock' and` package.json` file.
Removing them, and it work well.